# how to implement a java project as pluggable jar

Tags: java, jar

Need implement a module in java which i being used by multiple applications. So how can i create a java project which can be plugged into other projects as a jar? Appreciate any useful links.

Comment: What did you research?

Comment: i do not know where to start. Started doing research now.

Comment: Did you look at suggestions proposed when posting this question? You can also look at related questions.

Comment: Any jar should be usable by another java application, i.e. the classes in the jar. Where is the concrete problem?

Comment: yes. created a jar of common module and added the jar whereever required. its working fine. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

export the project as jar. And add this jar in the project classpath where this is required. Should be able to access the class files.